# Setting style for Android Notification setLastestEventInfo

Tags: android

Is it possible to set the style of a notification in Android?

```
  Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon,
        null,
        mSystem.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
        getResources().getString(R.string.initializing_notification_title),
        null,
        pendingIntent);
```

Unfortunately it's not possible to set the font styles programmatically in Android. Is there a way for me to set the font color and font size of this notification before it gets displayed?

Comment: Use a custom notification layout.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android SDK documentation they have a nice example of using custom notification layouts:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView